# Can't open Bootstrap modal in codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I can't open my modal in CodeIgniter.
I did a view for the modal and then I loaded in the controller. But when I click on the button, it doesn't show anything. No response. head have the Jquery and Bootstrap imports in the correct order.
Here i show you my code:

**cdashboard.php**:

```
//header
$this->load->view('UI/vheader');

//sidebar
$this->load->view('UI/vsidebar',$data);

//modals
$data['modaltarea'] = $this->load->view('tareas/vmodalnewtarea',NULL,TRUE);

//data in dashboard
$this->load->view('vdashboard',$data);

//footer
$this->load->view('UI/vfooter');
```

**vmodalnewtarea.php**:

```
<div id="newTareaModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newTarea" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" >
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Tarea nueva</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!--Importar plantilla-->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h3>Importar plantilla</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <!--Proyecto-->
              <div class="col-md-4">

              </div>
              <!--Fase-->
              <div class="col-md-4">

              </div>
              <!--Tarea-->
              <div class="col-md-4">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--Nueva Fase-->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h3>Nueva Tarea</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" required />
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <!--<table id="tableHitos" class="table table-bordered table-strip" >
                    <thead>
                      <th>
                        Hitos
                      </th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                  </table>-->
                  <a type="button" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <textarea id="txtaTarea" rows="5" placeholder="Descripcion" required>
                </textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <p>
          aaaaaa
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the view where I call the modal, on other view (**vrowfase.php**):

```
<div class="row fase">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
      <div class="callout callout-warning">
        <h4><?= $fase->nombre?></h4>
          <div class="progress progress-xxs">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="projectBar col-lg-10">
      <div class="row Bar">
        <?= $tareas; ?>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-app text-center" data-toogle="modal" data-target="#newTareaModal">
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
          Nueva Tarea
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

your modal id is

> newTareaModal

and your data-target in button is

> TareaModal

Comment: yes, yes, this is not the wrong thing, was the old code (ctrl z lol). I edited the question with the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

was a error writing.
on **vrowfase.php** I had "data-**toogle**" and is "data-**toggle**"

thank you anyway!